# Не отображается div на сайте

Tags: php, html, css

Не отображается div на странице, что бы не пытался сделать. Причем в index точно такой же код отображается как обычно. Хром показывает, что код есть, но не рисует. Никак не пойму в чем дело, буду очень благодарен за объяснение, или хотя бы намек, куда копать. Скрины страницы и индекса прилагаю. Код сайта одинаковый, потому в единичном экземпляре.
[image: На индексе]`[image: На странице]

```
.sheet {    
background-color: #FEFFFC;
padding: 10;
border: 1px solid #CACCC9;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-bottom: 90px;
margin-right: 35px;
font-family: Arial;
}

<?php
    require_once "site.php";
?>
<html>
<head>

    <?php
        head_view();
    ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#EDEFEB">
    <div class="sheet">
    <?php
        body_view();
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Возможно, где-то ломается верстка. Можешь показать код на странице? (Ctrl +U)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Насколько я понял, index-файл и CSS находятся в одной директории, а файл страницы - в другой.*
Если файл страницы находится не в той же директории, что и styles.css, нужно указывать путь к CSS, начиная *с корня сайта или с ближайшей общей директории*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
```

*И, на будущее, практически во всех современных браузерах есть инструменты разработчика, в которых, в свою очередь, есть вкладка **Source**. Пользуйтесь ей чаще.*

Comment: Спасибо, помог. Файлы находились в одной директории, но из-за того, что  href="/styles.css" писалось без слеша, он не мог его найти. При этом индекс спокойно все использовал

Answer (score 0):

попробуй добавить в стили

```
z-index:100;
```